# ASP.net Viewstate and Ports

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, port

In reviewing logs for several sites, I noticed that several of them reported Viewstate errors. While I was able to diagnose solutions for these, one thing I kept seeing is that in the exception logs it kept reporting port numbers:

```
ViewStateException information: 
Exception message: Invalid viewstate. 
Client IP: 1.2.3.4 
Port: 10189 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
```

From what I can see, the port numbers are usually high. My question is - what is this being used for? What is the relationship between viewstate and these ports? Does the client use these ports or is this something internal within the ASP.net pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

It's the way the TCP/IP works. The server listens on port 80, but then switches you to a different port so it can keep listening on port 80. It's a really low-level operation. There port numbers are high, as lower numbers are generally reserved. 34000 - 64000 is considered userspace.